# React hooks: how to access props within "mount" useEffect & not throw linting warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Unless I'm mistaken, this is valid code:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (prop1) {
      doSomething();
   }
}, []);
```

(prop1 is a prop). But when linting I get the following error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'prop1'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.
```

(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

I don't want to pass prop1 as a dependency because I would lose the "only run on mount" behaviour. But I need to access the prop to doSomething().

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you expect this prop’s value to potentially change on a re-render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks were new when this question was written, so maybe you already know this, but in case you or someone else wants to know:

React thinks that because your effect uses the value of prop1, it "depends" on prop1 and should be re-run whenever it changes. That's why the linter is complaining that it's not listed as a dependency.

However because you want the effect to only run "on mount", you want it to use the value of prop1 from the initial/first render, and never run again even if prop1 changes. This is at odds with the conceptual idea that the array lists all the variables the effect depends on, which is what the linter is focused on.

The solution alluded to in the [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) is to use useRef to keep track of whether or not this is the first render (edited):

```js
const firstRenderRef = useRef(true)

useEffect(() => {
  if (firstRenderRef.current) {
    firstRenderRef.current = false
    doSomething(prop1)
  }
}, [prop1])
```

This solution satisfies the linter, specifically because it follows the idea of listing all dependencies of the effect in the array. The ref allows the effect to also depend on a variable for whether this is the first render or not, but without rerendering when the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably raise this here.. [[ESLint] Feedback for 'exhaustive-deps' lint rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)

Though I get the feeling where this is a case where you should add an eslint "ignore" comment if you are sure you don't want the effect to run on update of `prop1`.

A legit case for relaxing the warning was raised here..
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-467896512

Also check what version of the plugin you are running..
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920#issuecomment-468801699

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
const usemount = ( functionToDoSomeThing, data ) => {
    useEffect( () => {
        functionToDoSomeThing( data );
    },[] );
};

usemount( console.log, props );
```

i define a function to do Something and pass it to hook

in example i use console.log function

Comment: Thanks! Yeah circumventing the issue is certainly an option but I think I'm going to wait for the issues for that particular linting rule to get resolved. It's very new & refactoring code just to avoid linting feels wrong. Thanks again!